# Varios videos en el reproductor de html5 en bucle

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Necesito que el reproductor de HTML5 reproduzca 5 videos en bucle. Sin tener que darle al play.

```
<video preload="true" autoplay="true" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
<source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="video5.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

No se si es necesario hacerlo con JavaScript. Si fuera así, apreciaría algo de ayuda.

Comment: Al comienzo yo también pensaba que se podía realizar de esta manera, luego me di cuenta de que cada source es como un respaldo, si la primera opción no funciona pasará a la segunda, sino a la tercera y así.

Comment: Utilizando Javascrit se podría indicar que cuando acabe el video, el "src" cambie por el siguiente video, pero no doy con el código navegando por la red.

Comment: Dale una mirada a este link http://thenewcode.com/792/Create-A-Simple-HTML5-Video-Playlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente ejemplo utilizo el evento "ended" para saber si el video se ha acabado. Si el video se ha acabado cambia el atributo src al siguiente valor del array `vids`.

Cuando llega al final del array vuelve a reproducir el primer video.

```js
// el array de los videos
let vids = ["https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/605876/video-player-video.mp4","https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"]
// la longitud del array de los videos
let leng = vids.length;
// un numero utilizado para saber que video se está reproduciendo
let n = 0;
// utilizo el evento "ended" para saber si el video se ha acabado
vid.addEventListener("ended",()=>{
// si el video se ha acabado cambia el atributo src
vid.setAttribute("src", vids[n%leng]);

n++;
}
)
```

```html
<video id="vid" preload="true" autoplay="true" muted="muted" volume="0" controls width="300" height="168">
 <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto. Gracias.